# Gradle build failed (zip END header not found)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm attempting to build a VR demo project in unity. I'm on Mac and I've tried installing Gradle through brew, downloading the zip file from the Gradle site, and the built in Gradle in Unity. All of these result in similar error messages. My Unity Gradle install doesn't look like the others I've seen online, however it still results in the same error message as if I install it manually

Console:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.4f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.4f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
XPC_FLAGS = 0x0
__CFBundleIdentifier = com.unity3d.unityhub
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined
HOME = /Users/nickash
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
JAVA_HOME = /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.4f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446283
XPC_SERVICE_NAME = 0
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.4f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3
USER = nickash
MallocNanoZone = 0
LOGNAME = nickash
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0x0:0x0
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446282
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.427IgHQNhn/Listeners
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
COMMAND_MODE = unix2003
TMPDIR = /var/folders/c_/qj4tqykd6pg7pk_j1fh7lw8m0000gn/T/
SHELL = /bin/zsh
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform wvr_ime_client-.aar (:wvr_ime_client:) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /Users/nickash/testing/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/wvr_ime_client.aar.
         > zip END header not found
   > Failed to transform wvr.common.utils-.aar (:wvr.common.utils:) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /Users/nickash/testing/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/wvr.common.utils.aar.
         > zip END header not found
   > Failed to transform wvr_client-.aar (:wvr_client:) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /Users/nickash/testing/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/wvr_client.aar.
         > zip END header not found
   > Failed to transform vr.client.abi-.aar (:vr.client.abi:) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /Users/nickash/testing/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/vr.client.abi.aar.
         > zip END header not found
   > Failed to transform wvr_permission_client-.aar (:wvr_permission_client:) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=integration, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /Users/nickash/testing/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/wvr_permission_client.aar.
         > zip END header not found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
]
stdout[
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <b417242467964bd1aa8aad6e355fdf88>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <b417242467964bd1aa8aad6e355fdf88>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <b417242467964bd1aa8aad6e355fdf88>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <b417242467964bd1aa8aad6e355fdf88>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <b417242467964bd1aa8aad6e355fdf88>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <b417242467964bd1aa8aad6e355fdf88>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <b417242467964bd1aa8aad6e355fdf88>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <b417242467964bd1aa8aad6e355fdf88>:0)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun() (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:188)
```

image of Finder in the unity specified Gradle install folder:
[not the full file structure, but it gives you an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbNYr.png)